# Call controller action from one application to another in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two applications that interact with each other. I need to create a database instance of a model in the second application that is created in the first. The below code works only when I call the method in the second application after creating `User` instance and saving it.

**app1_service.rb**

```
def send_user_data
  json_data = {}
  user = User.last
  json_data[:app1_user_id] = user.id
  json_data[:user_name] = user.name
  render json_data
end
```

**app2_service.rb**

```
def create_user
  response = App2Service.post( '/services/app1_service/send_user_data.json', query: { request: { authenticate: {auth_key: "#{APP_CONFIG[:auth_key]}"} } } )
    User.create(app1_user_id: response['app1_user_id'], user_name: response['user_name'])
end
```

What I want to do is to create the `User` instance in `app2` database whenever that `user` is created in `app1`. So I tried like this:

**users_controller.rb**

```
def create
  if @user.save

    Services::App1Controller.send_user_data(user)
end
```

**app1_service.rb**

```
def self.send_user_data(user)
  #Here I am not able to figure out how to call the action from the controller in the other application
end
```

What changes should I make so that it works as per the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

This case you should call app2 API in order to create a User on app2 database, something like: `/services/app2_service/send_user_data.json`. You should also create this API on app2.

If you really need this data synchronized, it's recommended to use PostgreSQL Multi-Master Replication to keep both databases with the same data, or Kafka events.